# How do you add an account using a connection string in VS 2015 using Cloud Explorer?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015

I can't for the life of me figure out how to add an external storage account to the `Storage Accounts` dropdown in the Cloud Explorer in VS 2015. I have Azure SDK 2.9.1 installed, and the Cloud Explorer extension installed.

In VS 2013, The `Azure` tab under `Server Explorer` had a `Storage` node/dropdown where I could add this by selecting "Attach External Storage...", but I can't seem to find where this is added in Cloud Explorer.

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Have you figured it out?

Comment: @DanielQiu not yet :( been using VS 2013 in the meantime.

Comment: what is your cloud explorer or Azure SDK versions in VS 2013? As I accidentally updated to the latest version and it has the same problem in my VS 2013. I wanted to revert back to the old "working " version. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielQiu Azure SDK 2.8.1.0
Cloud Explorer 1.0.51117.3

Comment: @DanielQiu I just found out about this http://storageexplorer.com/ try it out, it works really well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't actually able to get this to work, but Microsoft has released a new tool: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/ which works for my needs!